# Javascript blues in PHP: getElementById & getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, php, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

This should be simple enough, alas it's giving me issues:

I have a PHP page that gives me up to three different iterations of `td` contents. The first is shown with `display: table-cell`, and the others are hidden with `display: none`.

```
echo '<td style="display: table-cell" class="gameLineCell" id="'.$playerLine.'" colspan="3">';
```

&

```
echo '<td style="display: none" class="gameLineCell" id="'.$playerLine.'" colspan="3">';
```

I then have a link corresponding to each `td` option -- clicking it is supposed to run a function `loadLine` into which I pass a string that corresponds to the `td` ID. ID strings akin to 'EV-F1' -- five characters, a number, a hyphen.

```
echo "<a onclick='loadLine(".$playerLine.")' href='javascript:void(0)'>".$playerLine."</a>";
```

The script hides all `td`s of the class `gameLineCell`, and displays the one whose link was clicked.

```
<script>
    function loadLine(line) {
        var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('gameLineCell');
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            lines[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
            document.getElementById(line).style.display = 'table-cell';
    }
</script>
```

When I view the source of my PHP page everything renders properly -- my links show the proper strings in the `loadLine` brackets, each of my `td`s is present, the first showing and the others hidden -- however my links do not work. I've tried removing the `getElementsByClassName` sequence, running only the `getElementById`, though to no avail. Nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Much obliged to any help,

Andrew

---

**EDIT**: Source of the error? Javascript is cutting my strings! EV-F1 becomes EV. Looking into the whys and how fix now.

Comment: No errors on the console?

Comment: That should work (with the fix from Claudio Redi), so if not you should be getting errors in the console (as @Ja͢ck pointed out). Try to produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without PHP and post it to the question -- most likely, you'll figure it out while doing that, but if not it gives us something we can help you debug.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Yes, there's an error in the console. It's cutting my string off at the hyphen, e.g. `EV-F1` becomes `EV`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here related to proper escaping and enclosure of strings; I personally use `printf()` to print HTML, this is what it would look like:

```
printf('<td style="display: table-cell" class="gameLineCell" id="%s" colspan="3">',
    htmlspecialchars($playerLine, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
);
```

This piece of code in particular is tricky:

```
echo "<a onclick='loadLine(".$playerLine.")' href='javascript:void(0)'>".$playerLine."</a>";
```

The problem is that `$playerLine` doesn't contain JavaScript string enclosures and so it would attempt to resolve `EV-F1` into `EV - F1` (i.e., the subtraction of `EV` and `F1`). To fix that, you need to encode the variable using JSON and then apply HTML escaping:

```
printf('<a onclick="loadLine(%s)" href="javascript:void(0)">%s</a>',
    htmlspecialchars(json_encode($playerLine), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
    htmlspecialchars($playerLine), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
);
```

Comment: Yeehaw this works! Many thanks @Jack! I'll migrate on over to `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo on the code you show. There is an extra `)` here

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length); i++)
```

it should be

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
```

Comment: Good catch @Claudio Redi, but it still doesn't work! Even without the `getElementsByClassName` loop -- still doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrew: try inserting a breakpoint on function `loadLine` to see if the function is called